# Деактивация определенных кнопок

Tags: javascript, php

Есть таблица, в каждой строке есть кнопка "редактировать"

```
if ($sesrights == "admin" ) {
  echo "<td><form action='persona_redact_list.php' method='post'>
  <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row["id"] . "' />
  <input type='submit' value='Редактировать'>
  </form></td>";
}
```

`$row["id"]` - **ID** записи в базе
так я могу их скрыть, конечно могу использовать `disabled`.

А как деактивировать (или скрыть) часть кнопок, например где **id** = 1, 5, 10, 16 и т.д..

Comment: Создайте массив с нужными ID и проверяйте `row['id']` на наличие в массиве - есть, отключаете кнопку(или вообще не выводите

Comment: Про массив с id думал, но все-равно не доходит как реализовать, может какой пример скинете?

Answer (score 2):

Выглядеть это должно примерно так:

```
$mas = [1, 5, 10, 16];
if ($sesrights == "admin" ) {
      echo "<td><form action='persona_redact_list.php' method='post'>
      <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row["id"] . "' />";
      if (!in_array($row["id"], $mas)) { // Если id нет в массиве - выводим кнопку
          echo "<input type='submit' value='Редактировать'>"; 
      }
      echo "</form></td>";
}
```

Сами определите, каким образом и по каким условиям вам собирать массив исключений.

Или с отключением кнопки

```
$mas = [1, 5, 10, 16];
if ($sesrights == "admin" ) {
      $dis = in_array($row["id"], $mas) ? 'true' : 'false';
      echo "<td><form action='persona_redact_list.php' method='post'>
      <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row["id"] . "' />";
      echo "<input type='submit' value='Редактировать' disabled='". $dis ."'>";
      echo "</form></td>";
}
```

Comment: На php c 10 года ничего не писал, поэтому код может быть не оптимальный, однако для демонстрации "как это сделать" должно подойти )

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать JavaScript для скрытия кнопок с определенными ID. Например, можно добавить класс к кнопке с определенным ID и затем скрыть его с помощью CSS. Вот пример кода, который можете использовать:

```
<td><form action='persona_redact_list.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row["id"] . "' />
<input type='submit' value='Редактировать' id='editButton_" . $row["id"] . "'>
</form></td>

<script>
var hideIds = [1, 5, 10, 16];
for (var i = 0; i < hideIds.length; i++) {
    var id = hideIds[i];
    var button = document.getElementById('editButton_' + id);
    button.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

В этом примере, кнопки с ID 1, 5, 10 и 16 будут скрыты при загрузке страницы.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!!!

Comment: Переходите с `var` на `let` и `const`

Comment: @SwaD если ты не понимаешь чем отличается var от let и в каком случае их использовать, а так же const зачем применяют, не надо людей учишь)) Ты это написал потому что везде видишь что все так пишут?

Comment: Как раз таки наоборот. [var](https://learn.javascript.ru/var) это устаревшее определение переменных. Вот если вы так разбираетесь, то зачем вам в глобальной области переменные id и button?